# Re-set Editor Input of AbstractConfigurationEditor

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have a MultiPageEditorPart which contains two AbstractConfigurationEditor which I added via the `addPage()` [method](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fui%2Fpart%2FMultiPageEditorPart.html).

I have a rename file listener and reset the main editor input via `setInput()` and rename title `setPartName()`.

However I still need to change the editor input of two AbstractConfigurationEditor. But their `setInput()` method is protected and I cannot access it. 
How how can I call that method ?

Comment: What is `AbstractConfigurationEditor`?

Comment: [here](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipsescada/javadoc/0.2/org/eclipse/scada/ca/ui/editor/config/AbstractConfigurationEditor.html)

Comment: I am sorry this is a custom abstract class in my project and it extends EditorPart.

Comment: Well if it is your class you can add methods to the class to do what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added a method inside my abstract class to reset my editor input. :)

```
 public void newInput(IEditorInput i){
          this.setInput(i);
             }
```